# Flutter firestore update values of two fields for all documents in a collection everyday

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore there is a collection "students" which has two fields "date" and "onBus". I want to update these two fields everyday automatically based on the day date,
like "everyday reset "on_bus" to "0" and set "date" to today date for all students".

How can I do this for flutter app?

i try the following code but it does not work

```
Future<bool> resetStudentOnBus() async {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  String formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
  for (var doc in FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students').docs) {
    if (doc?.date != formattedDate && doc?.onBus == "1") {
      try {
        db.collection(FirebaseConstants.pathStudentUserCollection)
            .doc()
            .update({"on_bus": "0", "date": formattedDate}).then((value) {
          print("success");
          return true;
        }).catchError((onError) {
          print(onError);
          return false;
        });
        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: you can try this https://localcoder.org/can-firestore-update-multiple-documents-matching-a-condition-using-one-query

Comment: What does `doc?.date` look like in the database? Is it a string like the `formattedDate` that you're comparing it to?

Comment: yes in database it's like 2-5-2022

Comment: That seems like funny database design, would it be better to create a new record every day and preserve the existing data? Like, each day write a new document in the user's attendance collection if they are present on the bus. So if you have a doc for that day /user, they count as "on_bus", otherwise they don't? Or something like that?